# Using firewall rules to restrict app store access

Tags: app-store, firewall, openwrt

I'm using OpenWRT and playing with IPtables rules on my router.

I was wondering if there is a way of allowing only certain apps to be downloaded through the Mac App Store or Google Play Store using firewall rules (different app downloads might be indistinguishable).

Anyone knows how the Stores work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot restrict apps download using IPtable. The Router would need to look into the data packets that are transmitted and this is not possible using IPtables.
The only way you can restrict this is by either blocking app download completly by blocking access to the app store domains or by ensuring that the devices have a policy installed that tells them which apps are allowed to be installed.